# What is the semilinear form for this poisson equation?

Tags: finite-element-method

I am using finite element software to solve ODEs and PDEs. It requires the semilinear form. E.g When solving the poisson equation
$$\nabla\cdot((1+u^2)\nabla u) = -f$$
the semilinear form
$$\int_\Omega (1+u^2)\nabla u\cdot\nabla v - fvdx$$
is required.

What I would like to know is the semilinear form for the equation
$$\nabla^2 u = -f(u)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\nabla^2u$ is the Laplacian, it would most likely be

$$\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\nabla v + f(u)v.$$

Essentially it should be the nonlinear form that defines the weak formulation?